# debugfs set_inode_field ctime with nanoseconds

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, inode, ext4, ctime

I'm using `debugfs` to change the ctime of a file (programm rotine attached to ctime of this specific file) on an ext4 file system.

The therefor used command is:

```
debugfs -w -R 'set_inode_field foo/bar ctime 20130503145204' /dev/vdb1
```

but this is resulting in an ctime als followed:

```
myserver:~ # stat foo/bar 
  File: „foo/bar“
  Size: 1234        Blocks: 24         IO Block: 4096   reguläre Datei
Device: 1234h/1234d Inode: 1234567     Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: (  123/ whatever)   Gid: ( 1234/ whatever)
Access: 2021-02-12 21:17:51.146954174 +0100
Modify: 2021-02-12 14:51:32.152323937 +0100
Change: 2013-05-03 16:52:04.991865222 +0200
```

not as expected: `2013-05-03 16:52:04.000000000 +0200`

Reason, why it worked properly bevor is that the old ext3 FS stored ctime only at second resolution. the `inode structur size` in ext2/ext3 was 128 bytes. With ext4 this size incremented to 156 bytes (i_extra_isize = 28, see: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Size) resulting in nanosecond resolution.

How do I format the debugfs command to set the ctime to the exact nanoseconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little digging I managed to solve this problem. Solution: read the manual.

- https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Table
- https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Timestamps

debugfs supports setting of ctime/atime/mtime/crtime time_extra bytes with

```
set_inode_field foo/bar ctime_extra 0
```

The **ctime_extra** field is a **unsigned integer**, so the value of 0 gives the expected setting.

dtime was not widend and therefor does not support dtime_extra

Comment: debugfs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/sda2: Bad magic number in super-block while opening filesystem
set_inode_field: Filesystem not open

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a newer debugfs (both from ext2fsprogs 1.44.1 and 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014) works), which displays the inode timestamps as hexadecimal numbers as well (see the output of the `stat foo/bar` command below).

See below the debugfs commands to copy the ctime (nanosecond precision) from one inode to another.

First, get the ctime of the source inode:

```
stat foo/bar
```

From the output of `stat foo/bar`:

```
 ctime: 0xabcdef09:12345678 -- Wed May  4 02:40:09 2061
```

- abcdef09 is the numeric ctime value in hex,
- 12345678 is the numeric ctime_extra value in hex.
- Please note that the `Wed May...` part is timezone-dependent, run `TZ=GMT sudo debugfs ...` to get consistent results across systems. For the copying, we don't need this, because we copy the numerical values.

Then, to copy the ctime to the destination inode:

```
set_inode_field foo/bar2 ctime @0xabcdef09
set_inode_field foo/bar2 ctime_extra 0x12345678
```

The copy results can be verified with `stat foo/bar2`.